# Create Source Control System on NAS Drive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tfs, visual-sourcesafe, nas

i'd like to create a source control system running on a NAS Drive. As a Windows User, I've never been able to get Microsoft Visual Source Safe to work on previous NAS Drives, as internally most of them seem to use Linux rather than Windows. I always got a security denied error message.

Should most NAS Drives be able to host a source control system. I'm presuming that possiblly i should have tried to install subversion rather than visual source safe?
Or ideally i'd like to use Microsoft Team Foundation Server.

Should i be looking for a NAS Drive with NTFS? Is there any that someone can recommend?
Also will there be a performance issue?

regards

Kojo

Answer (score 2):

TFS uses SQL server as its storage mechanism.  It is not recommended to put SQL data files on NAS drives, due to the high latency.